# "DEPRECATION: Upgrade ember-cli-inject-live-reload version to 1.10.0 or above" warning will not go away after upgrade

Tags: npm, ember.js, visual-studio-code, ember-cli

I am new to working on an Ember front-end site and just recently received a warning stating the following:

> DEPRECATION: Upgrade ember-cli-inject-live-reload version to 1.10.0 or
>   above

I went ahead and ran a `npm audit fix` and `npm upgrade ember-cli-inject-live-reload`. When I run `npm show ember-cli-inject-live-reload version` it says 2.0.1. But, wen I re-run `ember s`, I get the same deprecation error. I tried closing and restarting VS Code, which did not work. Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it? Or, do I just ignore it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may have multiple versions of `ember-cli-inject-live-reload` installed, with the main one being 2.0.1, but some addon is bringing in an older version. To find out, try running `npm ls ember-cli-inject-live-reload`.

To avoid this kind of problem in general, I recommend `ember-cli-dependency-lint`. If you install it and then run `ember dependency-lint`, it will identify any addons where you have multiple versions installed.

Answer (score 1):

I get this message, when I add `"liveReloadOptions": {...}` or `"liveReloadJsUrl": "..."` to .ember-cli. liveReloadHost and liveReloadPort doesn't work at all.

I solved it by deleting this option from .ember-cli and modifying my apache config to use [mod_proxy_wstunnel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html) instead.

My apache config now looks like this:

```
[...]
ProxyPass "/server/" "!"
ProxyPass "/_lr/livereload.js" "http://localhost:4200/_lr/livereload.js"
ProxyPassReverse "/_lr/livereload.js" "http://localhost:4200/_lr/livereload.js"
ProxyPass "/_lr/livereload" "ws://localhost:4200/_lr/livereload"
ProxyPassReverse "/_lr/livereload" "ws://localhost:4200/_lr/livereload"
ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:4200/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:4200/"
[...]
```

My backend can be reached under localhost/server/ - which is why I use mod_proxy at all.